# Orion CB instance login

Tags: fiware-orion, filab

I have successfully created a Orion CB instance at fi-lab, and I am able to access via remote ssh. However, I am asked for a login user/password and all the standard user/password seems not to be valid.

What is the root password for "orion-psb-image-R4.1"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok, it is solved using the keypair and ssh -i <my_private_key> root@host

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved it, but just in case somebody is wondering I'll reply more fully to your question.

Due to security reasons, access to pre-built machines with username and password is disabled. You can **only** SSH into them using some kind of certificate of wich you have a private key (whether you created it on FIWARE Lab for this virtual machine or you had one prepared beforehand).